# global_queue with qos_class_user_interactive

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I try to understand GCD and wrote this code to find out run priority:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchImage()
    print(1)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
      print(2)
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      print(3)
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) { 
      print(5)
    }
  }
```

I got next result in the console:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 5
>
> 3

So the question is:

**Part 1**: Why 3 is after 5 (main_queue has highest priority?)

**Part 2**: And why 2 is higher that 3 and 5 as well?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Presumably this is run on the main thread. Did you mean for 2 to be sync or did you miss the a?

Comment: @Wain thank you, missed that. But result is the same. May be you're right but why task with lower priority runs first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bear in mind: this is multi-threading, on a multi-core device, writing output to a log that you don't know the thread safety and internal management of...

That said:

1. 1 is first because it's synchronous
2. 2 is second because it's also synchronous
3. 3 is not next because it's pushed into the queue of things waiting to run on the main thread run loop and you don't know what else is already in that queue
4. 5 is before 3 because it's (basically) the same priority but it's running on a queue that probably does't have anything else waiting (`QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE` ~= main thread priority)

Note, I say ~= because I haven't checked the exact values and it may differ slightly though I expect the priority values to match, otherwise 'interactive' wouldn't mean much...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So if I say that main_queue and global_queue with priority of QOS_CLASS_USER_INTRACTIVE is the same I would say wrong? If I change 2 to async nothing changes.

Comment: So even if 2 is async it goes before 3 and 5 inspite of  it's QOS_..._INITIATED

Comment: the exact order isn't hard and fast, and the things you're asking the OS to run are very small and take basically zero time, so it's just going to run them. when you get into time consuming tasks then the priority will start to play more of a part

Comment: you mean if I do something heavier than print functions in the same condition they would print other order?

Comment: not necessarily if the print is at the start, but say each thing printed at the start and end and did 1 million calculations in between, then you should start to see changes in the end time as the million calculations would get interrupted part way through to allow higher priority things more time to run

Comment: So they start in FIFO order but end in unpredictable order, right?

Comment: I asking about priority because in apple Docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html) they say that user_interactive maps with main_thread. So I believe that if I take global_queue with the ...user_interactive so I should be on main_thread.

Comment: they are queued in the order they are made, as they're all queued from main it's FIFO but you shouldn't think of it that way. user interactive is the same priority but not the same queue, the whole point of it is to run in the background but at a suitable priority because the user is waiting

Comment: That is what I wanted to hear! Thank you!

Comment: @Wain how is 2 synchronous? It says dispatch_async.

Comment: @wm.p1us - asking for the global_queue with QOS_USER_INTERACTIVE does not give you the main thread. It gives you a thread with the same QOS (priority if you will)

Answer (score 0):

The result is the order of the priorities.
`QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE` means user forground process, so highest priority.
`QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED`  means user is waiting for the result of the job, so very high priority.
And the main queue is normal work load as when user has seen everything and its job.