# Grand central dispatch , QOS user interactive vs get main queue

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm doing a tutorial on grand central dispatch. Essentially, the instructor had some code inside of a closure which were long running tasks, so he put everything inside of a background queue (Code is way too long to write, no source code provided). In short he had this format

```
dispatch_async(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND,  {
    //time consuming tasks which should not be on main queue
})
```

However inside the closure where everything was on a background queue, there was some code that updated the user interface. I was taught (mainly by udacity), that all UI updates should be on the main queue. Hence

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...
```

although the instructor, instead used

```
dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0), {...}
```

I understand that this is appropriate since QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE is meant for immediate tasks as its linked with user interface. However what are the advantages of using that vs `get_main_queue`?

Comment: maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735946/global-queue-with-qos-class-user-interactive) and [GDC cheat sheet](https://lionhylra.wordpress.com/2015/09/06/gcd-for-swift-cheatsheet/) can answer your question

Answer (score 4):

`dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)` returns a global *concurrent*
queue which is suitable for task that need to be done "quickly" in order to update
the user interface. Tasks on this queue have a higher priority than e.g. tasks on a
 `QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND` queue. But this is *not* the main queue.

The UI update itself must be done on the main queue which you get with
`dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Comment: The docs say you can update the UI---"– QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE: The user interactive class represents tasks that need to be done immediately in order to provide a nice user experience. Use it for UI updates, event handling and small workloads that require low latency. The total amount of work done in this class during the execution of your app should be small."

Comment: @RyanTCB: See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit: For the most part, use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

Comment: Docs also say to use QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE. Which I why I think the original question is asked. As it's confusing  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html

Comment: See link in my previous comment table 4-1 *correction: doesn't say "to use" it not that you "can use".sorry

Comment: @RyanTCB: The UIKit documentation is quite clear. I understand the QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE docs as I wrote above: For task that have to be done quickly *in order* to update the user interface.